# Update a JSON formatted JavaScript object based on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Having two JSON formatted js-objects:

```
obj1 = { prop1: 1,
         prop2: 2,
         prop3: 3 }

obj2 = { prop1: 1,
         prop2: 3 }
```

What is the best js-practise to update obj2 into obj1, that also removes properties? Typically in a jQuery/angular context. Resulting in:

```
obj1 = { prop1: 1,   // not updated, nor overwritten
         prop2: 3    // updated
       }             // prop3 removed
```

Must also deal with nested objects and arrays.

Comment: If you are deleting the properties not present in obj2 from obj1.
Then you always ending up with obj2.
What i mean is that resulting json will always be obj2 irrespective of what obj1 has.
Could you please provide a better example.

Comment: I have been looking into both jquery's and angular's extend functions, but these does not delete removed properties.

Comment: What @CyrilCherian is trying to say is that it sounds illogical what you're trying to do, because you can actually just type: `obj1 = obj2;` and will  do what you asked.

Comment: That is correct, Cyril Cheria. But then obj1 is changed to obj2. I need to keep obj1 since it has attached listeners.

Comment: Can't you just reattach the listeners? Can you update your question with another example or deeper explanation about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function merge_objects(obj1,obj2){
    for (var attr in obj2) { obj1[attr] = obj2[attr]; }
    for (var attr in obj1) { if(!obj2[attr]){ delete obj1[attr]} }
    return obj1;
}
```

Comment: This should work, with two comments: don't forget to check for hasOwnProperty and watch out for the case obj2 has the property "attr" but it is "false" or "undefined" or 0: your condition will evaluate to "true" and the property will be deleted from obj1... try something like if (!(obj2.hasOwnProperty(attr))) { delete obj1[attr] } instead :)

Comment: Thanks Cyril and Octav. I'll go with a recursive version of this.

Answer (score 1):

To compare objects you can use [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)(obj1, obj2).
For merging you can check [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) but it won't delete missing elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy(or clone including arrays/child objects) contents of object2 into object1, try using jquery [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

```
Please find jsfiddle [here][2]
```